# jQuery plugin for a simple input box for comma-separated tags with autosuggest

Tags: jquery, plugins, tags, autosuggest

I'm searching for a jQuery plugin with following functionality:

1. It should display an input box, in which tags would be put in like so: 'bees, beads, beards'.
2. When a user is typing a tag, it should display an autosuggest box for the user's input.
3. The display should be plain and simple: just plain-text comma-separated tags.
4. It should allow tags containing spacebar (e.g. 'funny cats').
5. Comma symbol should be used for separation, not keystroke for ',', because some non-English keyboard layouts have commas assigned to other keys.

Is there such a plugin and if so, where can I find it?

Comment: Check this topic

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446128/jquery-autosuggest-for-multiple-words-in-single-textbox

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/), which pretty much does everything you want.

Check out the "Multiple Select" feature on their site.

**Deprecated**

> This version of Chosen is not currently under active development while
> we decide on its future direction.

Comment: It's really good-looking, but it doesn't seem to allow comma-separated tags. It also doesn't fulfill the requirement for plain-text display.

Comment: @exizt: You could mimic plain text display with CSS. As far as commas go - well, either you implement support for them yourself or that library is not the right one for you.

Comment: Deprecated This version of Chosen is not currently under active development while we decide on its future direction.

Comment: @HamzaZafeer Thanks for the edit. This is one of the reasons why questions for and answers with library recommendations are considered strongly off-topic these days. Back when this answer was written, things were a little less rigid.

Answer (score 4):

[jQuery Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) seems to fit your demands.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't fit the third criteria ('The display should be plain and simple: just plain-text comma-separated tags'), but perhaps there is an option for that? I'll look into it. Oh, and it also relies on the ',' keystroke for tag separation.

Comment: After the option pops up, use enter. That's me trying to convince you to wait for the autocompletion to finish ;) Perhaps [jQuery UI's autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) is a better fit?

Comment: But that's the thing: I need exactly comma-separated tag input. jQuery UI's autocomplete is good, but I'm not very good with JS, and making it work with separate tags in one input box would be too much for me (e.g. 'bees, bea|' (`|` showing the position of cursor) should give the user autosuggest for the 'bea' part of input).