# jquery autosuggest for multiple words in single textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

how to cofigure the Jquery autosuggest plugin to support for multiple words in a single textbox.

Eg. If i want to type "STACK OVERFLOW" in a textbox. as i start typing ST.. It should autosuggest for "STACK" and after space, if i type OV.. It should show OVERFLOW.

I need to configure autosuggestion for **individual words** in a single textbox.

NOTE: I dont want to show STACK OVERFLOW as start entering "ST".

Similar to "Tags" suggestion in Stackoverflow, but not a tag as individual word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Jquery UI which can be found here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple

It'll show you an example to have multiple words in a single textbox.

As for seperating the STACK from OVERFLOW, you can do that by separating them in the source value you give the plugin, such as:

```
var source = ["STACK","OVERFLOW"];
```

This will suggest them independently.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks denislexic. once the user selects the "STACK", it appends with ",". how to avoid this?

Comment: You have to change the function split(), there is an regular expression.  If you just want a space, instead of this /,\s*/ you can use /\s/ or /\s\s*/.  Not too sure, I'm not a regex expert.

Comment: used /\s\s*/ and removed comma in terms.join(" "); Thank you very much denislexic. Its working as expected.