# Create a tags box like stackoverflow's

Tags: html, css, tags

I'd really like to know how to arrange a tag box like the one we have here a Stackoverflow.

I'm almost there, I just need to arrange the tags in a way that when the tags container width is overpassed, the tags get pushed to the left instead of to the right or downwards.

So far I have this CSS code:

```
#tagsContainer{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    height: 28px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
#tagsBox{
    float: left;
}
#tagsTxtBox{
    float: right;
}
```

And this HTML code:

```
<div id="tagsContainer">
    <div id="tagsBox"></div>
    <div id="tagTxtBox"><input type="text" id="autocompletes" /></div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look this links: [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) and [Token Input](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/). Both I found here on the forum: [jQuery plugin for a simple input box for comma-separated tags with autosuggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260359/jquery-plugin-for-a-simple-input-box-for-comma-separated-tags-with-autosuggest)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by setting the `direction` on .tagsBox to `rtl` (stands for 'right to left'), and added `'text-align: left'`. The text is still aligned with the left border of the box, but when  it is too long and overflows the box, it'll overflow the box's left side.

This does change the order of your tags. But, since that's what they are, the order doesn't really matter I guess.